# Implicit pointer cast in parameter and argument of functions

Tags: c, pointers, casting

If 2 function definitions are:

```
    void func(struct Node *arg){...}

    void func2(void *arg){
      func(arg);
      ...
    }
```

but they are called like:

```
    struct Node *node = (char *)malloc(6);
    func2(node)
```

I think `node` is implictly casted to `void*` and then to `struct Node*`, so I don't need to do something like:

```
    func2((void *)node);
    or func((struct Node *)arg);
```

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Not related, but why `struct Node *node = (char *)malloc(6);`, instead of `struct Node *node = (struct None *) malloc(6);`?

Comment: Or [better](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc), `struct Node *node = malloc(6);`

Comment: @interjay or `struct Node *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));`?

Comment: @H2CO3 Of course, I didn't even notice that.

Comment: @H2CO3 Yup, was just asking out of curiosity. btw nice thread here: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: @informatik01 If you check my answer, that link is included :)

Comment: @H2CO3 It was way too fast ))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There's no such thing as "implicit casting". There is explicit type conversion (casting) and implicit type conversion (type coercion or promotion).
2. Since `void *` is compatible with any *data* pointer type (and if your implementation conforms to POSIX, then it's compatible with function pointers too), your assumption is right:

`T *object = malloc(size);`

is right regardless to the type `T` denotes. The same applies to function arguments, of course.

Some (myself included) even argue that [casting in this case is dangerous, decreases readability and should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).